# Making various groupings

Tags: python

My data set is a list of people either working together or alone.

I have a row for each project, and columns with names of all the people who worked on that project. If column 2 is the first empty column in a row, it was a solo job. If column 4 is the first empty column in a row, there were 3 people working together.

I have the code to find all pairs. In the output data set, a square N x N is created with every actor labelling columns and rows. Cells (A,B) and (B,A) contain how many times that pair worked together. A working with B is treated the same as B working with A.

An example of the input data, in a comma delimited fashion:

```
A,.,.
A,B,.
B,C,E
B,F,.
D,F,.
A,B,C
D,B,.
E,C,B
X,D,A
F,D,.
B,.,.
F,.,.
F,X,C
C,F,D
```

I am using Python 3.2. The code that does this:

```
import csv
import collections
import itertools

grid = collections.Counter()

with open("connect.csv", "r") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    for line in reader:
        # clean empty names
        line = [name.strip() for name in line if name.strip()]
        # count single works
        if len(line) == 1:
            grid[line[0], line[0]] += 1
        # do pairwise counts
        for pair in itertools.combinations(line, 2):
            grid[pair] += 1
            grid[pair[::-1]] += 1

actors = sorted(set(pair[0] for pair in grid))

with open("connection_grid.csv", "w") as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow([''] + actors)
    for actor in actors:
        line = [actor,] + [grid[actor, other] for other in actors]
        writer.writerow(line)
```

My questions are:

1. If I had a column with months and years, is it possible to make a matrix spreadsheet for each month year? (i.e., for 2011, I would have 12 matrices)?
2. For whatever breakdown I use, is it possible to make a variable such that the variable name is a combo of all the people who worked together? e.g. 'ABD' would mean a project Person A, Person B, and Person D worked together on and would equal how many times ABD worked as a group of three, in whatever order. Projects can hold up to 20 people so it would have to be able to make groups of 2 to 20. Also, it would be easiest if the variables should be in alphabetical order.

Comment: A quick recommendation/request.  Please go back and correct the indentions on your "with open" block of code.  As you know, indentions matter in Python. Without them the reader is left guessing at what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Sort your projects by month & year, then create a new 'grid' for every month. e.g.:

Pull the month & year from every row. Remove month & year from the row, then add the remaining data to a dictionary. In the end you get something like {(*month*, *year*): [*line*, *line*, ...]} . From there, it's easy to loop through each month/year and create a grid, output spreadsheet, etc.

2) `''.join(sorted(list)).replace('.','')` gives you the persons who worked together listed alphabetically.

```
import csv
import collections
import itertools

grids = dict()
groups = dict()

with open("connect.csv", "r") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    for line in reader:
        # extract month/year from the last column
        date = line.pop(-1)
        month,year = date.split('/')
        # clean empty names
        line = [name.strip() for name in line if name.strip()]
        # generate group name
        group = ''.join(sorted(line)).replace('.','')
        #increment group count
        if group in groups:
            groups[group]+=1
        else:
            groups[group]=1
        #if grid exists for month, update else create
        if (month,year) in grids:
            grid = grids[(month,year)]
        else:
            grid = collections.Counter()
            grids[(month,year)] = grid
        # count single works
        if len(line) == 1:
            grid[line[0], line[0]] += 1
        # do pairwise counts
        for pair in itertools.combinations(line, 2):
            grid[pair] += 1
            grid[pair[::-1]] += 1

for date,grid in grids.items():
    actors = sorted(set(pair[0] for pair in grid))
    #Filename from date
    filename = "connection_grid_%s_%s.csv" % date
    with open(filename, "w") as fp:
        writer = csv.writer(fp)
        writer.writerow([''] + actors)
        for actor in actors:
            line = [actor,] + [grid[actor, other] for other in actors]
            writer.writerow(line)

with open('groups.csv','w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    for item in sorted(groups.items()):
        writer.writerow(item)
```

Comment: This is great, I have days so I added to your code 'month,day,year'..can add if you like. One problem is that I am getting spaces between my rows and columns and could not get rid of them. And by variables, I should have been more clear, I would like a spreadsheet that just lists all of the groupings (in alpha order) and the column next to it would put how many times that grouping had occurred in the data. So for the data given every grouping is unique, save one, so I would have (with a , splitting the output columns) A,1; AB,1; BCE,2 (because BCE and ECB are equivalent); BF,1; etc

Comment: Also, how can I label the file names with year then month since I have years of data

Comment: Okay, I've edited the code to print out groups into a csv too.

It already generates filenames by month then year. For vice versa, switch the code above to say (year,month) instead of (month,year) except in month,year = date.split('/')

I'm not sure why you're getting spaces in your rows & columns, need to see the input file for that.

I hope you're using SO to learn and not to get a custom script done! The script above does most of what you require, you should experiment with it yourself to make it work like you require. Hint: for eliminating extra spaces, we use .strip()

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to use this to learn. I solved the extra row space problem by adding    ,newline="" after     with open(filename,"w"